# How to check imported packages in unpickled file

Tags: python, pickle, python-importlib

Funny problem here. I have pickled an object instantiated from a custom-made class. It houses some SciKit-Learn and Datetime objects. Nothing fancy.

Now, when I unpickle it, I am getting the following error:

```
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(166)_get_module_lock()
KeyError: 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements'
```

Now, I am 99% sure I did not pack (via composition) any object into attributes of that custom class, which has anything to do with sqlalchemy. Yet, the error persists. I was wondering, if there was any way in Python to check the list of imported modules in a pickled file?